# Javascript regex with lookahead and lookbehind being wrong?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I'm using the following regex to match the word '**stores**' between '**/**' and '**?**' with a possible forward slash '**/**' before the '**?**' but for some reason it fails saying there's an invalid quantifier. Any idea why it might be wrong and quatifier is that? I tried removing '**/?**' but it still says the same thing.

```
var n=str.match(/(?<=\/)stores\/?(?=\?)/);
```

Thanks!

Comment: FYI JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds

Comment: oh, I see. Any workarround applicable to this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the invalid part: (?<=/) - javascript's lookahead is (?=y); it doesn't support lookbehinds, which is what I'm assuming you were trying to use.
This regex should work though:

```
\/stores\/?\?
```

which matches:

a forward slash,

followed by the string 'stores',

followed by zero or one forward slash,

followed by a question mark.

Comment: thing is i want to match the word stores only (even without the potentially present '**/**' which i couldn't manage to do anyway) Sorry i am just a newbie to regex. Any tips? http://regexr.com?35omo

Comment: Oh I see... hmm would something like \/stores(?=\/?\?) work? The lookahead makes sure that the trailing / and ? aren't matched, so now you're left with an an array with a bunch of '/stores' strings in them. Depending on what you want to do with the matches, I guess you can then use array.forEach(function(element, index, array) {array[index] = element.slice(1)} to get rid the /.

Comment: i see, i was trying to avoid additional processing, but apparently i have no choice thank you very much!